# Set Route Color in GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

I am using the WPF version of Gmap.NET.

This feels like a stupid question....but I can't figure out how to change the stroke color/width of a route.

In winforms GMapRoute has property Stroke that can be set as you would expect

```
GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(route.Points, "My route");
r.Stroke.Width = 2;
r.Stroke.Color = Color.TurdBrown;
```

The WPF version seems very different and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could access to these properties using a casting, here is my code:

```
GMapRoute mRoute = new GMapRoute(route.Points);
mRoute.RegenerateShape(MainMap);
((System.Windows.Shapes.Path)mRoute.Shape).Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
((System.Windows.Shapes.Path) mRoute.Shape).StrokeThickness = 20;
```

Firts of all I created the GMapRoute, then I generated its shape in the map, then I modified the shape changing color and thickness.

I hope that this can help you.

Answer (score 4):

I think use *RegenerateShape* for creating Shape is not good for performance.
It is better to setup style of line before adding route to map.

```
List<PointLatLng> routePath = List<PointLatLng>();
routePath.Add(new PointLatLng(Lat1,Lon1));
....
routePath.Add(new PointLatLng(LatN,LonN));
GMapRoute groute = new GMapRoute(routePath);
groute.Shape = new Path() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), StrokeThickness = 4 };
map.Markers.Add(groute);
```

Comment: This solution works beautifully and is IMO more intuitive to use.